# How do I get the menu ID based on the menu title?

Tags: routes

I am looking for a function to call like in the following snippet:

```
get_menu_id("my menu title");
```

Do you have any tips?

Comment: Found a nice snippet here http://jan.tomka.name/blog/programmatically-creating-menu-items-drupal#comment-23

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, you can't.

The title you see on the page and the title in the database are the same only in the case you are running an English-only website and the title_callback is `t()`.  If you are using Drupal 7, you aren't overriding string in settings.php.
Otherwise, the title is generated dynamically and it's literally impossible to find its value in the database.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could loop through the results of `menu_get_names()`, as in:

```
function get_menu_id($menu_title) {
    $menu_names = menu_get_names();
    foreach ($menu_names as $menu_name) {
        $menu = menu_load($menu_name);

        if ($menu['title'] == $menu_title) {
            return $menu_name;
        }
    }
}
```